# JavaScript method passing parameters

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters, dojo

I used `dojo` 8 years ago, so i am very new to the `dojo` 1.7+.  I want to define a method that takes a parameter, but it also has requirements on `dojo` module (lang). So I tried the following.

```
 <script>
    function fillReportTable(repId) {
        require(['dojo/_base/lang'], function(lang) {

             //just example calls to lang..
             var obj = { a:"b", c:"d" };
             var thing = lang.clone(obj);
            repId = repId + 1;
        });

        return repId;
    };

    alert(fillReportTable(13))
</script>
```

But `alert(fillReportTable(13))` shows the whole function definition  instead of number 14.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `dojo`, then **almost everything** need to be an `AMD module` and probably just a little `vanilla Javascipt`. So, you can turn your function into an `AMD module` and is easy

**myApp/fillReportTable.js**

```
define(['dojo/_base/lang'],function (lang) 
{                
    return function fillReportTable(repId) {
        var obj = { a:"b", c:"d" };
        var thing = lang.clone(obj);
        return repId + 1;
    }
});
```

then, you can `require` it

```
require(["myApp/fillReportTable"], function(  fillReportTable )
{
    console.log(fillReportTable(123));
});
```

but if you continue with your approach, then you can solve it using a `Promise`

```
function fillReportTable(repId){
   return new Promise(function(resolve){
        require(['dojo/_base/lang'],function (lang){                
            var obj = { a:"b", c:"d" };
            var thing = lang.clone(obj);
            resolve(repId + 1);
        });
   });  
};
```

How to use it

```
fillReportTable('Hello World').then(function(repId){
    console.log(repId);
});
```

Note that `Promise` is an [ECMAScript6 feature](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage)

Hope it helps